# Socket Client Sends nothing

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a Problem: I have a Socket Client on my Android Phone and a Java Socket Server on my PC. Server -> Android works perfektly, but Android -> Server doesn't work.

This is my sending Method on my Phone:

```
public void sendMessage(String cmd, String parameter) {
        String msg;
        if(!parameter.equals(""))
            msg = cmd+";"+parameter;
        else
            msg = cmd+";null";

        Log.v(TAG,"Send: "+msg);

        DataOutputStream bos;
        try {
            bos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            bos.write(msg.getBytes("US_ASCII"));
            bos.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

And this is The receiving on my Server:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {
        try {
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            String message = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println("#"+this.ID+": Received: "+message);
            obs.setID(ID);
            obs.proceedMsg(message);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            this.isRunning = false;
            System.out.println("#"+this.ID+": Closed Instance");
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone an Idea? :)

Thanks

Comment: does your sent data from pc well received in the android side ?

Comment: yes, server -> Phone works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use writeUTF on a client side. Your server is expecting UTF as you use readUTF method.

writeUTF writes additional 2 bytes in the beginning which indicate block length. When you use plain write method, you do not supply those bytes and this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks thats correct, I haven't seen this method in the doku :)